# Testing an AngularJS factory with Karma (Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm struggling with testing an AngularJS factory using Karma + Jasmine.

I am unable to inject my factory to `OfficerValidationService` variable.

What am i doing wrong?

*Note: the file is loaded properly*

**Factory:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('darthvader').factory('OfficerValidationService', [function(){

  var OfficerValidationService = {};

  OfficerValidationService.something = function() {
    return true;
  };

  return OfficerValidationService;

}]);
```

**Code:**

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  describe('OfficerValidationService Spec', function() {

    var OfficerValidationService;

    beforeEach(function() {
      angular.module('darthvader');
    });

    beforeEach(module('darthvader', function($provide) {
      $provide.value('OfficerValidationService', OfficerValidationService);
    }));

    it('is very true', inject(function(OfficerValidationService){
      alert('=====' + OfficerValidationService + '=====');
      var output = OfficerValidationService.something();
      expect(output).toBeTruthy();
    }));

  });
}());
```

**Output:**

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.17 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket yc_qTseOCArRtZLAXSTZ with id 97647403
ALERT: '=====undefined====='
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) OfficerValidationService Spec is very true FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'OfficerValidationService.something')
        at /Users/chuck/Desktop/sandbox/dashboard.darthvader/test/karma/unit/services/officerValidationService.js:25
        at invoke (/Users/chuck/Desktop/sandbox/dashboard.darthvader/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3917)
        at workFn (/Users/chuck/Desktop/sandbox/dashboard.darthvader/public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2155)
    undefined
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 28 of 28 (1 FAILED) (0.102 secs / 0.131 secs)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to call `angular.injector`:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  describe('OfficerValidationService Spec', function() {

    var OfficerValidationService;

    beforeEach(function() {
      angular.module('darthvader');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function() {
      var $injector = angular.injector(['darthvader']);
      OfficerValidationService = $injector.get('OfficerValidationService');
    }));

    it('is very true', function(){
      var output = OfficerValidationService.something();
      expect(output).toBeTruthy();
    });

  });
}());
```

Comment: Why `var $injector = angular.injector(['darthvader']);` instead of `beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {});` ?

Comment: EDITED code example. I suppose having an explicit declaration may have been valuable to understand where it's coming from

Answer (score 3):

To add to [martynas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002520/testing-an-angularjs-factory-with-karma-jasmine/25002759#25002759), here is a simplified version:

`module()` is the shorthand of [angular.mock.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module)
`inject()` is the shorthand of [angular.mock.inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) (same as [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector))

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  describe('OfficerValidationService Spec', function() {
    var OfficerValidationService;

    beforeEach(module('darthvader'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (OfficerValidationService) {
      OfficerValidationService = OfficerValidationService;
    }));

     it('OfficerValidationService should exist', function() {
        expect(OfficerValidationService).toBeTruthy();
    });


  });
}());
```