# karma test returning validateAmount is not a function

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I'm trying to test scope function which will check due amount, but while running the test I'm getting `validateAmount is not a function`.

app.js

```
var ManagmentApp = angular.module("ManagemntApp", ['ngRoute', 'angularModalService', 'ng-fusioncharts']);
ManagmentApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
     $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/CandidateForm.html',
        controller: 'cntrlrCandidate'
    }).when('/CandidateList',{
          templateUrl: 'templates/CandidateList.html',
          controller: 'cntrlrCandidateList'
    }).when('/CandidatesProfile', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/CandidateProfiles.html',
        controller: 'cntrlrCandidateProfile'
    }).when('/HostelStatistics', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/HostelStatistics.html',
        controller: 'cntrlHostelStatistics'
    }).when('/:id', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/CandidateForm.html',
         controller: 'cntrlrCandidate'
    });

}]);
```

cntrlrCandidate.js

```
ManagmentApp.controller("cntrlrCandidate", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "HostelManagementService", "$filter","HostelManagementIndexDBService", function ($scope, $routeParams, HostelManagementService, $filter,HostelManagementIndexDBService) {

    $scope.validateAmount = function () {
    var vrAmount = $scope.Candidate.Amount;
    var vrTotalAmount = $scope.PerMonthCharge;
    if (+vrAmount < +vrTotalAmount) {
        $scope.IsValidAmount = false;
        $scope.Candidate.DueAmount = (+vrTotalAmount - +vrAmount);

    } else {

        $scope.IsValidAmount = true;
        $scope.Candidate.DueAmount = 0;            
    }
}


}]);
```

test.js

```
describe("ManagemntApp ", function() {

beforeEach(module('ManagemntApp'));
 var scope;
var cntrlrCandidate,
$location;

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller,$rootScope){
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   cntrlrCandidate = function() {
            return $controller('cntrlrCandidate', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        };;
}));


    it('test amount', function() {

     scope.Candidate={};
     scope.Candidate.Amount=2000;
     scope.validateAmount();
      expect(scope.IsValidAmount).toEqual(true);
    });


});
```

I couldn't figure out what making notice.

This is the error I'm getting.[image: TestError]

**Update1:**

When I wrote like this the error message is below.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller,$rootScope){
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
 //  cntrlrCandidate = function() {
            cntrlrCandidate= $controller('cntrlrCandidate', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
       // };;
}));
```

Please check this error: [image]

**Update 2:**

I tried this way, please correct me if I did anything wrong.

```
describe("ManagemntApp ", function() {
var HostelManagementIndexDBService,HostelManagementService; 
beforeEach(module('ManagemntApp'));
 var scope;
var cntrlrCandidate,
$location;

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller,$rootScope){
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
 //  cntrlrCandidate = function() {
    HostelManagementService = {}; 
    HostelManagementIndexDBService = {};
    module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('HostelManagementService', HostelManagementService);
    $provide.value('HostelManagementIndexDBService', HostelManagementIndexDBService);
    });

    cntrlrCandidate= $controller('cntrlrCandidate', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
       // };;
}));


    it('return will pass the Amount', function() {

     scope.Candidate={};
     scope.Candidate.Amount=2000;
     scope.validateAmount();
      expect(scope.IsValidAmount).toEqual(true);
    });


});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002520/testing-an-angularjs-factory-with-karma-jasmine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cntrlrCandidate = function() {
            return $controller('cntrlrCandidate', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        };
```

You have defined the function `cntrlrCandidate` but not calling anywhere.

You need to call it first then you will get your controller;

Add this line after the `cntrlrCandidate` defination;

```
var ctrlCandidate  =cntrlrCandidate ();
```

OR

better if you define like this instead of defining above function.

```
cntrlrCandidate = $controller('cntrlrCandidate', {'$scope': scope});
```

**EDIT :**

Your controller required following Dependency `HostelManagementService` and `HostelManagementIndexDBService` which you not provided.So,you need to mock up it.

Add the following script.

```
var HostelManagementIndexDBService,HostelManagementService; //declare at top

// add in beforeEach
HostelManagementIndexDBService = {}; 
HostelManagementIndexDBService = {};
module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('HostelManagementService', HostelManagementService);
  $provide.value('HostelManagementIndexDBService', HostelManagementIndexDBService);
});
```

UPDATE :

```
describe("ManagemntApp ", function() {
    var HostelManagementIndexDBService, HostelManagementService;
    beforeEach(module('ManagemntApp'));
    var scope;
    var cntrlrCandidate,
        $location;

    beforeEach(function() {

        HostelManagementService = {};
        HostelManagementIndexDBService = {};


        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('HostelManagementService', HostelManagementService);
            $provide.value('HostelManagementIndexDBService', HostelManagementIndexDBService);
        });

        inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {

            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            cntrlrCandidate = $controller('cntrlrCandidate', { '$scope': scope });
        })
    });


    it('return will pass the Amount', function() {

        scope.Candidate = {};
        scope.Candidate.Amount = 2000;
        scope.validateAmount();
        expect(scope.IsValidAmount).toEqual(true);
    });


});
```

Comment: I tried this way also var ctrlCandidate  =cntrlrCandidate ();
But that couldn't solve my issue. :-(

Comment: Ofcourse 'm using those for other functionality but now i'm only trying to test that function then why it needed, can you please explain?

Comment: whenever u testing any controller,factory,services...etc,  u need to provide theDependancy that needed otherwise angular will give DI error same way when u run the application.and that is now u getting in karma console

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but still I couldn't resolve the issue. :-(

Comment: Yes, I did small google search with your hint thank you very much. it was fixed